# How to create data using local variable and append to gallery control in Power Apps

Tags: canvas, controls, gallery, powerapps, local-variables

I want to create monthly expenditure details like different expenditures and their prices. Once, click on the add button, it will be appended to the gallery on the same screen. Is it possible or not?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but the solution depends on what is the data source in your gallery:

1. If the data source is a collection, on the button's OnSelect property you need to use the `Collect()` function to append the new data to the existing gallery.
2. If the data source is external data like a SharePoint List, you'll have to use the `Patch()` function to send the data to the source.

In both cases the gallery will automatically reflect the changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-clear-collect-clearcollect
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-patch